# FCM Notification using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I managed to send notification message from PHP file and send to mobile phone using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

Once the user click on the notification message on mobile tray, how can I redirect to another layout with same message plus time and date?

Here is my code in FirebaseMessagingService.java (using Android Studio)

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);



    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

check this.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody)
{
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: change PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT into PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)..?

Answer (score 1):

// in service file

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Log.d("Send","msg" +messageBody);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"msg" +messageBody ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
        intent.putExtra("msg",messageBody);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

// in Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
                String text = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                Log.d("Received","msg" +text);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Received" + text ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
```

Comment: code in //in Activity will be added on MainActivity.java?

Comment: cannot resolve Intent, Log.d, Toast. & .getStringExtra..? what that means..?

Comment: show me your code so i can understand where is your mistakes...i think you are forgetting some things