# Get intent extras if activity is running

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm struggling with this problem: I have some notifications and I want to pass intent extras to an activity, even if the application is already running.

Some solutions I found here on S.O. didn't work for me, like adding:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to the manifest, I'm also using this:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

like someone suggested.

My code is this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("New website change.");
mBuilder.setContentText("Changed: " + url);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key", url);
notificationIntent.putExtras(b);

notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), id, notificationIntent, 0);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NotificationService.this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

And then inside the activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null) {
  url = b.getString("key");
  editText.setText(url);
  webView.loadUrl(url);
  webView.requestFocus();
}
```

Any help will be welcome, I will release this app's code as open source, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what do you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I have some urls in the notifications, and I want to open it on the activity, which has a webview. If the activity is not running, (i.e. another activity is running) the notification is able to send its extras, while if the activity is on foreground, it can't get the extras (in this case the url).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021484/fcm-notification-using-android-studio/40021597#comment67322451_40021597

Comment: K. If activity is in foreground, you can send a broadcast with the url directly to the activity. It will update your URL variable in your activity. And if background the process will work as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

This will always return the `Intent` that was used to *create* the activity instance.

In cases where the activity already exists, and you are using `Intent` flags (e.g., `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or manifest settings (e.g., `singleTop`) to direct control back to that activity, you need to override `onNewIntent()`. The `Intent` delivered to that method is the `Intent` that was used to bring the activity back to the foreground.

Answer (score -1):

override the onNewIntent method in the activity and getting the value from the bundle in this method.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

String yourvalue = getIntent.getExtras.getString("key");

    }
```

Comment: you should look for extras in intent field, not getIntent()